# point of inflection of $f(x)={2x\over 1+x^2}$

Tags: real-analysis

could any one tell me how to determine the point of inflection of $f(x)={2x\over 1+x^2}$

Answer says It Has exactly $3$ point of inflection separated by a point of Maxima and a point of Minima.

I found $f''(x)=0$ at two point.

Answer (score 3):

The derivative, via the quotient rule, is

$$f'(x) = \frac{(1 + x^2) (2) - (2x)(2x)}{(1 + x^2)^2} = 2 \frac{1 - x^{2}}{(1 + x^2)^2}$$

Ignoring the leading $2$, the numerator of the second derivative is thus

$$(1 + x^2)^2 (-2x) - (1 - x^2) \cdot 2 (1 + x^2) 2x$$

Simplifying, this is

\begin{align}
(1 + x^2) \left((1 + x^2)(-2x) - (1 - x^2)(4x)\right) &= -2x (1 + x^2) \left(1 + x^2 + 2(1 - x^2) \right) \\
&= -4x (1 + x^2)(3 - x^2)
\end{align}

This has three real roots at $0, \pm \sqrt{3}$, and two imaginary roots at $\pm i$.

Comment: You'd have $(1+x^2)^4$ in the denominator, so $\pm i$ is not actually a root. That doesn't change the answer to the question though.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: After doing $f''(x)$, look for the points in which $f''$ is undefined or vanishes. Here you'll find three points (real) as $$x=0,-\sqrt{3},+\sqrt{3}$$
Now try to find the point that $f''(x)$ changes its sign. For example, around $x=0$, we see that $f''(0^+)>0$ and $f''(0^-)<0$. This kind of point is the one which you wanted.

[image]

Comment: Perfect graph for the task at hand! +1